# iPhone development on beta version?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, version, beta

I've downloaded latest version of Xcode and iOS SDK:

iOS 5.1 beta 3 and Xcode 4.3 Developer Preview with iOS 5.1 SDK beta 3.

When I check the Xcode about version following information is displayed:

Xcode 4.2.1 (834) (4D502)
iphone OS: 5.0 (9A334)

I'm not sure whether I face any problems or not when I submit my app with beta software. If so what's the best procedure here? revert back to production version and develop the app?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't submit apps built by a beta version of Xcode anyway.

But you are still using the stable version (4.2.1).

That's probably because Apple changed the way they distribute Xcode. The beta version (4.3) is a single app in your application directory. But the stable version (4.2) is located in /Developer.
So the beta version could not overwrite the stable version because they are stored in different places.

Since you still have the stable version there is no need to revert anything.
It even looks like you accidentally used the stable version all the time ^^

For the future: Make sure to keep the stable Xcode if you want to submit apps.